# Can't Launch Freemind in Ubuntu 15.10 - Please Advise

Tags: linux, ubuntu

For a long while I've had difficulty launching the program Freemind in Ubuntu 15.10:

```
sudo apt-get install freemind
```

I submitted a bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/1445598

I'm hoping that someone here can view the details linked above and suggest a workaround.

I've created a mind map that, due to this problem, I'm having to remote into a windows OS (with freemind install) to view my map.

The map was created via freemind in Ubuntu, but my ability to launch freemind in Ubuntu has recently degraded to where the program simply won't open at all; the splash screen comes up when I launch freemind, but it never gets to the main program window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiago Stürmer Daitx just referenced a [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+bug/1510009/comments/24) on the [bug-report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/1445598).

I confirm this worked for me. Thanks Tiago!

Comment: The problem of only link answers, is the referenced workaround page does not work anymore.